# Trabajar con los Datos de un Archivo CSV que Ingresa como Parámetro de una Función

Tags: python

Teniendo un archivo CSV llamado "C1-S5 Valores Asignados.csv" que ingresa a una función "def control()" como parámetro con nombre: "asignacionfile", de la siguiente manera:

```
def control(asignacionfile):

# Código de la Función.

control('C1-S5 Valores Asignados.csv')
```

Es necesario llamar los datos incluidos en el archivo CSV dentro de la función y realizar algunas operaciones con ellos. Los datos que contiene el archivo son los siguientes:

```
['Cliente', 'Punto de Distribución', 'ID del Camión', 'Carga a entregar (Lts. O Cajas)', 'Tiempo de despacho\n(minutos)']
['Lactocaribe', '1', '4', '1492', '31']
['Lactocaribe', '2', '1', '1359', '39']
['Lactocaribe', '3', '5', '1289', '54']
['Lactocaribe', '4', '4', '1325', '30']
['Lactocaribe', '5', '2', '1368', '55']
['Lactocaribe', '6', '4', '1233', '34']
['Lactocaribe', '7', '2', '1450', '38']
['Lactocaribe', '8', '1', '1325', '41']
['Lactocaribe', '9', '4', '1279', '55']
['Lactocaribe', '10', '5', '1425', '53']
['Lactocaribe', '11', '1', '1362', '39']
['Lactocaribe', '12', '5', '1382', '51']
['Lactocaribe', '13', '4', '1213', '39']
['Lactocaribe', '14', '1', '1377', '42']
['Lactocaribe', '15', '3', '1378', '47']
['Lactocaribe', '16', '4', '1237', '42']
['Lactocaribe', '17', '3', '1344', '51']
['Lactocaribe', '18', '1', '1276', '38']
['Lactocaribe', '19', '2', '1446', '35']
['Lactocaribe', '20', '4', '1274', '49']
['Lactocaribe', '21', '2', '1397', '39']
['Lactocaribe', '22', '3', '1387', '42']
['Lactocaribe', '23', '1', '1480', '34']
['Lactocaribe', '24', '4', '1360', '30']
['Lactocaribe', '25', '3', '1472', '50']
['Lactocaribe', '26', '1', '1417', '31']
['Lactocaribe', '27', '5', '1359', '47']
['Lactocaribe', '28', '2', '1317', '52']
['Lactocaribe', '29', '1', '1360', '35']
['Lactocaribe', '30', '2', '1363', '43']
['Frigoaves', '1', '1', '85', '11']
['Frigoaves', '2', '4', '88', '14']
['Frigoaves', '3', '4', '93', '14']
['Frigoaves', '4', '4', '87', '14']
['Frigoaves', '5', '4', '98', '14']
['Frigoaves', '6', '4', '100', '13']
['Frigoaves', '7', '2', '92', '10']
['Frigoaves', '8', '4', '93', '11']
['Frigoaves', '9', '2', '88', '10']
['Frigoaves', '10', '3', '97', '14']
['Frigoaves', '11', '3', '90', '12']
['Frigoaves', '12', '1', '91', '10']
['Frigoaves', '13', '1', '92', '15']
['Frigoaves', '14', '3', '89', '12']
['Frigoaves', '15', '2', '97', '13']
['Frigoaves', '16', '1', '96', '14']
['Frigoaves', '17', '2', '89', '12']
['Frigoaves', '18', '3', '100', '12']
['Frigoaves', '19', '4', '91', '12']
['Frigoaves', '20', '4', '85', '15']
```

Cuando intento llamar los datos al interior de la función utilizo la misma estructura de datos que se utiliza para leer un archivo CSV de la siguiente manera:

```
import csv

with open("asignacionfile", "r", encoding='utf-8') as work_data:
    for line in work_data:
        print(line, end='')
```

Lo hago de esta manera por que desconozco como hacerlo de otra. Pero obviamente el resultado es un error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'asignacionfile'
```

Debo trabajar al interior de la función con los parámetros dados que contienen la información del archivo pero que no puedo leer y trabajar con ellos. ¿Cómo puedo hacer la lectura de esta información dentro de la función y luego trabajar con ella?

Comment: `open(asignacionfile, ....)` sin las comillas (es una variable)

Comment: Craso error de mi parte... Gracias Pollo por hacerme caer en cuenta, estoy aprendiendo pero todavía se me pasan cosas tan básicas como esta.

Comment: Nunca se deja de aprender ;-)